# scipy.stats.ks_2samp for masked and unmasked data give different results when no values are masked

Tags: python, scipy

There are two versions of the scipy.stats.ks_2samp function. [scipy.stats.ks_2samp](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ks_2samp.html) is the standard version, and [scipy.stats.mstats.ks_2samp](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mstats.ks_2samp.html) is the version in which "Missing values are discarded". Given distributions in which *no entires* are missing, the results are different. Why? Code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import ks_2samp
from scipy.stats.mstats import ks_2samp as ks_2sampm

a = np.array([1, 3, 6, 8, 8])
b = np.array([2, 3, 4, 6])

ks_2samp(a, b)# statistic=0.40000000000000002, pvalue=0.75428850089034016
ks_2sampm(a, b) #(statistic=0.39999999999999997, pvalue=0.86916357240334474)
```

Why the different p-values? I'm using scipy v1.0.0

Comment: This discrepancy is probably worth discussing on the scipy github site.  Can you create a new issue for this at https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues?

Comment: I've now created one here: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/8341